# generalization of midpoint-convex

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Let

f : (a,b) → R is a midpoint-convex function (I didn't say continuity).

Here I'd like to verify following inequality ""directly"".

f( (x1+x2+x3)/3 ) ≤ (f(x1)+f(x2)+f(x3))/3

..

I can easily demonstrate for n=2^k

BUT not case for n=2^k, HOW can I demonstrate this inequallity?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: See http://www.mathsolympiad.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/Convex-functions.pdf for example.

Comment: @copper.hat /  Thank you. Really helpful :-)

Comment: It may be worth noting that this "downward induction" is in the spirit pioneered by Cauchy's proof of AMGM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_Cauchy_using_forward.E2.80.93backward_induction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you can do it for $n=2^k$, specifically $n=4$, then
$f(\frac{(x_1+x_2+x_3+(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3)}{4})\leq \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)+f((x_1+x_2+x_3)/3)}{4}$
rearrange to get n=3 case. Same approach can be generalized to any non $2^k$ number.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I want. (Sorry for being late check your answer.)