# Mathematical induction inequality involving sines

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, induction

Let $0<A_i<\pi$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$. Use mathematical induction to prove that $$\sin A_1+\sin A_2+\cdots+\sin A_n\le n \sin\left(\frac{A_1+A_2+A_3+\cdots+A_n} n\right)$$ where $n\ge 1$ is a natural number.`

The inequality holds true for $n=1$. I assumed that it holds true for $n=k$. But I was unable to prove that it holds true for $n=k+1$. Please help me.

Comment: Use $\sin (\alpha+\beta)$ formula.

Comment: Can you show me the working steps using the same?

Comment: Try to prove $n=2$ by using trigonometric sum to product identity, then use induction to prove if it's true for $n=2^k$, it's true for $n=2^{k+1}$. For $n\neq 2^k$, look at my answer of the following question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939869/generalization-of-midpoint-convex/939889#939889 for the hint.

Comment: @frank000 but if it is true for $2^3=8$ you then only proof that it is true for $2^4=16$, so is it true for $11$?

Comment: @johannesvalks, yes, you use $A_1, A_2,... A_{11}, (A_1+A_2+...A_{11})/11,(A_1+A_2+...A_{11})/11,(A_1+A_2+...A_{11})/11,(A_1+A_2+...A_{11})/11,(A_1+A_2+...A_{11})/11$ for $n=16$ case you get $n=11$ case.

Comment: @frank000, I doubt you get it, when true for $n=16$ you get $(A_1 + A_2 + \cdots A_11)/16$,

Comment: The key is to recognize that the sine function is concave on $[0,\pi]$.  I used this property in my answer.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the sine function is [Concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) on $[0,\pi]$ so that for any points $x$ and $y$ on $[0,\pi]$ and any value of $t\in(0,1)$, we have

$$\sin(tx+(1-t)y)\ge t\sin x+(1-t)\sin y \tag 1$$

Now, letting $x=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i$, $y=A_{n+1}$, $t=\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $1-t=\frac{1}{n+1}$ in $(1)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i\right)&=\sin\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}A_{n+1}\right)\\\\
&\ge \frac{n}{n+1}\sin\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}\sin\left(A_{n+1}\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

It is key to note that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i\in[0,\pi]$.

Next, we could apply the inequality in $(2)$ to the sum on the right-hand side of $(2)$ and through a recursive process arrive at the desired inequality.

But the OP specifically asked to show that the inequality of interest through induction.  So, to that end, we establish a base case.  Using $(1)$ with $t=1/2$, we see that

$$2\sin \left(\frac{A_1+A_2}{2}\right)\ge  \sin A_1+\sin A_2$$

Next, we assume that for some integer $n$, we have

$$n\,\sin\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)\ge \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin(A_i) \tag 3$$

Using $(3)$ in $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i\right)&\ge \frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin(A_i)\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}\sin\left(A_{n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sin(A_i) \tag 4
\end{align}$$

where after multiplying $(4)$ by $n+1$ yields the desire result.

Comment: Is it that simple ;) Vote up!

Comment: @johannesvalks Yes.  In fact, we don't need induction unless we think of recursion as induction.